# How to view all the classes in Spark examples JAR

Tags: java, apache-spark, jar

I am trying to do `run-example classname`. To do this, I need to know the class name. I need to be able to hit the TAB button, so the class are listed. Example,

`java org.apache.spark.examples. <TAB>`, or

`run-example org.apache.spark.examples. <TAB>`, or perhaps

`spark-class org.apache.spark.examples. <TAB>`

should list BinaryClassification for example, plus all other classes in the jar.

I have exported classpath, but still I am not able to get the classes in the jar appear.

`export CLASSPATH=$SPARK_HOME/jars/*:$SPARK_HOME/examples/jar/*`

Comment: What shell are you using? Personally, I don't know of any that have the functionality you're after.

Comment: I am using bash and running Cent OS.

Comment: perhaps a web link to all the examples (by class names) will do. I just need to look it up from somewhere. I have searched online, but it seems that the source file names in Spark src repo do not correspond to the compiled class name.

Comment: `jar tvvf <somefile.jar>`; or open your jar file with any zip archive manager.